# R Shiny put content of a TextInput in sql queries

Tags: r, sqlite, shiny, textinput, shinydashboard

I'm facing a problem with R shiny and sqlite. My app is supposed to authenticate the user and load his/her preferences.

Here is my code  :

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)

############################
#    Database functions    #
###########################

# Connect the user to the dtabase app
connect <- function(userName,pwd){
    #Put a generic path here
  db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname = "my_path/database.db")
  #Query to get the correct passwd
  qry = paste('SELECT password from USERS where name = "',userName,'"')
  res= dbGetQuery(db,qry )

  ifelse(res==pwd,"connected","unable to connect to the database")
  dbDisconnect(db)

}

function(input, output,session) {

  observeEvent(input$connectButton, {
   userName= renderPrint(input$username)
   print(userName)
   userPwd = paste(input$password)
       connect(user = userName,pwd = userPwd)

  })
```

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("Authentification"),
textInput('username', label="User name"),
textInput('password', label= "password"),
actionButton("connectButton", label='Connect'),
actionButton("subscribeButton",label='Subscribe')   
)
)
```

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
####### UI
ui <- source("ui.R")
####### Server
varserver <- source("server.R")
####### APP
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = varserver)
```

My problem is when I want to put the content of the TextInput for the queries. I've tried several methods

With the current version, renderPrint(input$username) returns me something what seems to be a function but it doesn't seem to be useful.

I also tried an other way using only

```
userName=paste(input$userName)
```

This returns me the content of the *textField* but when i integrate it to the query it puts

```
[1] "SELECT password from USERS where name = \" test \""
```

and then I got the error

```
Warning: Error in matrix: length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

My objective is to have a query like this

```
"Select password FROM USERS where name = "username"
```

with `username` representing the content of the *TextInput*.

EDIT

I know use this version for the query, and it put a syntaxly correct query

```
qry = paste0('SELECT password from USERS where name = \'',userName,'\'')
res= dbGetQuery(db,qry )
```

but I face this problem now :

```
Warning: Error in matrix: length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

when I run the method

```
connect(db,qry)
```

I think the problem comes from the way i get the content of the TextInput : I use

```
function(input, output,session) {

  observeEvent(input$connectButton, {
   userName= paste0(input$username)
   userPwd = paste0(input$password)
       connect(user = userName,pwd = userPwd)

  })
```

What do you think about this ?

Comment: Try `paste0()` rather than `paste()`. The latter inserts spaces between terms by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which work

```
connect <- function(userName,pwd){
    #Put a generic path here
  db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname = "my_path/database.db")
  #Query to get the correct passwd
  qry = paste0("SELECT password from USERS where name = \'",userName,"\'")
  res= dbGetQuery(db,qry )
  res = paste0(res)
  ifelse(res==pwd,print("connected"),print("unable to connect to the database"))
  dbDisconnect(db)
}
```

I just cast arguments between simple quotes